# Eliminar duplicados en consulta sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente tabla donde almaceno las entradas y salidas de unos trabajadores en mi empresa ( id, numero_personal, fecha_entrada, fecha_salida).

Estoy intentando listar la ultima presencia de cada empleado y lo hago mediante la siguiente consulta.

```
SELECT id, numero_personal, fecha_entrada, fecha_salida FROM FICHAJES 
WHERE        (ID IN
                             (SELECT    MAX(id) AS Expr1
                               FROM     FICHAJES 
                                 where      fecha_salida is null
                               GROUP BY numero_personal ))
UNION

SELECT id, numero_personal, fecha_entrada, fecha_salida FROM FICHAJES 
WHERE        (ID IN
                             (SELECT    MAX(id) AS Expr1
                               FROM     FICHAJES 
                               GROUP BY numero_personal ))
```

```
1070    722 2007-03-01 00:00:00.000 2007-06-30 00:00:00.000
1075    723 2007-03-07 00:00:00.000 2007-06-06 00:00:00.000
1080    724 2007-03-08 00:00:00.000 2007-06-08 00:00:00.000
218     725 2007-03-19 00:00:00.000 2007-04-19 00:00:00.000
219     726 2007-03-21 00:00:00.000 2007-04-16 00:00:00.000
220     727 2009-03-23 00:00:00.000 NULL --> duplicado
1087    727 2007-03-26 00:00:00.000 2007-06-26 00:00:00.000 --> duplicado
1089    728 2007-03-26 00:00:00.000 2007-06-26 00:00:00.000
227     729 2009-04-20 00:00:00.000 NULL-> duplicado
1097    729 2007-04-09 00:00:00.000 2007-06-30 00:00:00.000-> duplicado
1102    730 2007-06-21 00:00:00.000 2007-09-21 00:00:00.000
1107    731 2007-06-21 00:00:00.000 2007-09-21 00:00:00.000
225     732 2007-04-10 00:00:00.000 2007-04-16 00:00:00.000
```

Esta consulta me devuelve registros duplicados  en el caso de que el trabajador tenga una entrada con fecha_salida = null , es decir, este trabajando.

Si elimino el segundo select de la unión, solo me muestra los trabajadores que estan trabajando actualmente.

```
220     727 2009-03-23 00:00:00.000 NULL
227     729 2009-04-20 00:00:00.000 NULL
```

Si elimino el primer select, me muestra los datos mas antiguos de la tabla para ese id, no los actuales.

```
1070    722 2007-03-01 00:00:00.000 2007-06-30 00:00:00.000
1075    723 2007-03-07 00:00:00.000 2007-06-06 00:00:00.000
1080    724 2007-03-08 00:00:00.000 2007-06-08 00:00:00.000
218     725 2007-03-19 00:00:00.000 2007-04-19 00:00:00.000
219     726 2007-03-21 00:00:00.000 2007-04-16 00:00:00.000
1087    727 2007-03-26 00:00:00.000 2007-06-26 00:00:00.000 --> aqui deveria devolverme el que tiene fecha de salida null, el presente
1089    728 2007-03-26 00:00:00.000 2007-06-26 00:00:00.000
1097    729 2007-04-09 00:00:00.000 2007-06-30 00:00:00.000 --> aqui deveria devolverme el que tiene fecha de salida null, el presente
1102    730 2007-06-21 00:00:00.000 2007-09-21 00:00:00.000
1107    731 2007-06-21 00:00:00.000 2007-09-21 00:00:00.000
225     732 2007-04-10 00:00:00.000 2007-04-16 00:00:00.000
```

¿Como puedo solucionar esto?
¿Hay alguna manera de eliminar de la consulta si tiene el mismo id, el que no tenga valor null en fecha salida?

Comment: Bienvenido csb95 a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: No me queda claro el motor de la base de datos ¿`sql-server` o `mysql`?

Comment: el motor es sql-server

Comment: para empezar creo esta mal tu tabla muestra la estructura de la misma, no deberias de tener repetidos, para entradas y salidas creo deberias de buscar informacion de como el sistema TRESS hace sus registros y te evitarias muchos problemas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una forma muy cómoda en SQL server es generar un numerador por `numero_personal` y ordenando por `fecha_entrada` descendente mediante [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql), de esta forma, si filtramos aquellos dónde el numerador sea 1 deberíamos quedarnos con la presencia más nueva.

```
WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT id, 
          numero_personal, 
          fecha_entrada, 
          fecha_salida,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY numero_personal ORDER BY fecha_entrada DESC) Rn
          FROM FICHAJES              
)
SELECT id, 
       numero_personal, 
       fecha_entrada, 
       fecha_salida
       FROM CTE
       WHERE Rn = 1
```

---

- El `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY numero_personal ORDER BY fecha_entrada DESC)` es el que genera un numerador que reinicia con cada `numero_personal`
- Con `WITH CTE AS` generamos una ["common table expresión"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) que utilizamos más abajo, pero bien podríamos hacerlo con una subconsulta.

Comment: muchas gracias, me ha funcionado tu solución.